# What might be causing the faulty shifting on my bike?

Tags: derailleur-rear, shifting, sprocket

I bought a used bike that has 8 speed cogs and 3 speed chainrings. The front shifts great but the back regularly fails on the 6th and 5th speeds. I know a bit about adjusting the shifters so I can say that they are currently set up right. What I'm not sure with is which component is causing the failure. The shifter, cable, and chain are new but the cogs, rear derailleur, and hanger came with the bike.

Comment: What do you mean by 'fails on the 6th and 5th speeds'? Fails how? Do you mean it fails to shift to those spockets? Shifting up or down? Does the chain slip over the sprockets?

Comment: Have you changed the cable, as it might be partially stuck? Have you tried to adjust the indexing (ass explained by the many videos available on the Net)?

Comment: @Argenti It fails both ways(up and down). The way I see it, the derailleur doesn't line up with the sprockets only at the 5th and 6th speeds, it's good everywhere else.

Comment: @Carel yes, the cables are new and the indexing is good.

Comment: A bent derailleur hanger can cause weird indexing issues

Comment: Can you post pictures?  That show the derailleur with the chain on the problem gears?  Also one that shows gear spacing without the chain in the way?  Someone may have installed a cassette that's made of separate cogs with spaces incorrectly.